# Signed Hex to Signed Int Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've seen a lot of questions converting hex to int, but these are all of the unsigned-> unsigned variety.  How could I convert signed hex to an Int?

eg.

```
somefunc('0xfffff830')
= -2000
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question implies that you are dealing with 32-bit signed integers
(otherwise `0xfffff830` could not be considered as negative),
so this would work:

```
let num = "0xfffff830"

let x = Int32(truncatingBitPattern: strtoul(num, nil, 16))
println(x) // -2000
```

`strtoul()` converts the hex string to an unsigned integer `UInt`, and 
`Int32(truncatingBitPattern:)` creates a (signed) 32-bit integer
from the lowest 32 bits of the given argument.

---

Updated for **Swift 4:**

```
let num = "0xfffff830"
let x = Int32(bitPattern: UInt32(num.dropFirst(2), radix: 16) ?? 0)
print(x) // -2000
```

Comment: This handles both signed and unsigned and is nice and short, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use conversion to unsigned and then convert the unsigned to signed.

```
let num = "0xfffff830"
var result: UInt32 = 0
let converter = NSScanner(string: num)
converter.scanHexInt(&result)

print(unsafeBitCast(result, Int32.self)) // prints -2000
```

Comment: Thanks! this handles both positive and negative values, and is another solution.

Comment: Also a good solution, I only would prefer `Int32(bitPattern: result)` over `unsafeBitCast(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

An approach

```
var hex = UInt32(0xfffff830)
let signedHex : Int
if hex > UInt32.max / 2 {
  signedHex = -Int(~hex + 1) // ~ is the Bitwise NOT Operator
} else {
  signedHex = Int(hex)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not cover positive range

Comment: @vadian can you please help for reverse process(signed array of byte to hex).